# Ruby on Rails 3: How to pass a parameter to a select box in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a **Client** model that can have many **Projects**.

These are my view files:

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <%= f.submit Create %>
<% end %>
```

**_fields.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :client_id %><br/>
    <%= f.select(:client_id, current_user.client_names) %>
</div>
```

This is easy and works great.

But is there a way to create a Project from within a **Client** view as well?

For example on the client edit page it would be nice to have a link *New Project for this Client* that leads to the above *New Project* form, but with the respective client preselected in the select box.

Can this be done somehow?

I can't seem to find a way to pass the Client ID to the *New Project* form.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but requires passing the client id to the new_projects_path.  This can be done by nesting the routes to projects inside of clients, or just appending the client id.  The difference would be URLs that look like the following:

```
/clients/1/projects/new
- or -
/projects/new?client_id=1
```

In your projects controller, you should be able to instantiate the @project variable with a preselected client:

```
@project = Project.new :client_id => params[:client_id]
```

Comment: Hey Chris, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I forgot that Rails treats form parameters and get variables equally, so now I can simply do `<%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path(:client_id => @client.id) %>` in my Client view and the client ID gets added to the URL. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You're going to use accepts_nested_attributes_for :project in your Client model. Nesting this will allow you to do something like

```
<%= f.fields_for :project do |p| %>
<fieldset>
<%= p.text_area :content %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Check out the railscasts episode #196 on Nested Model Form.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the solution was even simpler in this case (see below).